# Rails 4 Has One Update Pb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-one

I have a bit of a problem with a "has one" association on my app.

What I want to achieve is to be able to attach an optional quote to the topic. The quote can only be used once (in other words, if it's used for topic 1, it can't be used for any other topics).

I have a Topic model and a Quote model.
Topic has one quote.
Quote belongs to topic.

I also want to be able to attach a quote to other models (ex. Profile Model).

I'm really confused on what to do on my "edit topic" view as well as in the controller. I thought it would work like a "one to many" association, which I had no problem configuring. Somehow the "has one" is more complicated (for me!)

What I'd like is to have in the "edit topic" view a radio list of the available quotes which I can freely update. (Same for the "new topic" view).

My current controller:

```
 def edit
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @quote = @topic.quote
  @packages = @topic.packages
  @books = @topic.books
  @tasklists = @topic.tasklists
  @links = @topic.links
  @terms = @topic.terms
end

def update
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  if @topic.update_attributes(topic_params)
    flash[:success] = t('helpers.success-update', model: "topic")
    redirect_to backend_topics_url
  else
    render partial: 'edit'
  end
end

def topic_params
  params.require(:topic).permit(:topic_id, :theme_id, :cover, :topic_status, :topic_access, :slug, *Topic.globalize_attribute_names, :quote_attributes => [:id, :topic_id], :package_ids => [], :book_ids => [], :link_ids => [], :tasklist_ids => [], :term_ids => [])
end
```

My current Topic model:

```
has_one :quote
accepts_nested_attributes_for :quote
```

My current Quote model:

```
belongs_to :topic
```

And my "Edit Topic" view:

```
  <h4>Quote</h4>
  <% if @quote %>
     <h5>Current quote</h5>
     <%= @quote.quote %> <%= link_to('[change]', '#') %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.input :quote, :collection => Quote.all, :label_method => :quote, :label_value => :id, :checked => @quote.id, as: :radio_buttons %>
```

I'm sure there is something obvious that I'm missing but I can't figure out what.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
- Vincent

Comment: If a quote can only be used for one topic doesn't quote `has_one :topic`?

Comment: Are you using Rails 4?  Try f.collection_radio_buttons(:quote, :topic_id, @available_quotes, :id, :quote_name)

Comment: Yep i did it try but it threw an error (undefined method merge).

Comment: I think I'm missing something more obvious somewhere else. I keep double-checking the permit section on the controller or my form but can't figure it out. Frustrating but thanks anyway!

Comment: After a few hours digging through my code, I still can't figure out what's wrong.

Basically all I want to do is to be able to add one quote to the topic and also add one topic to the quote.

I manage to do the belong_to without problems. 
The inverse is more delicate. It needs to set to NULL the current topic and assign the new id with the new topic selected.

I know I'm doing something wrong either with the nested form, the strong parameters or the update (does it need a build association?). I can make it work with many to many associations.

Why this doesn't work? Frustration!

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you want to have quote belong to multiple models, you will need a polymorphic association.  Otherwise, you would need to add multiple foreign ids to quote like this: topic_id, profile_id etc and that will get messy fast.  You can view a screencast on polymorphism here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised

has_one and belongs_to is basically the exact same as has_many and belongs_to except you are only dealing with 1 record instead of a collection of records.

For your current setup - in your edit action you need to fetch all the quotes that are not associated to any Topics.  You can do that like this:

`@available_quotes = Quote.where(topic_id: nil)`

and then:

```
  <%= f.input :quote, :collection => @available_quotes, :label_method => :quote, :label_value => :id, :checked => @quote.id, as: :radio_buttons %>
```

instead of

`Quote.all` in your form which is returning all quotes.

If you move to a polymorphic model, watch the screencast, and you would replace "commentable_id" in the screencast with something like "quotable_id" and then in your edit action to find the unassigned quotes you would do this:

`@quotes = Quote.where(quotable_id: nil)`